# How do I create a scrollable div?

Tags: html, css

I am relatively new to coding and I am looking to re-create this http://prntscr.com/e73jze which I designed in Photoshop. Could anyone give me the simplest way to make this?

Many thanks

Comment: You can use jquery lightslider to easily achieve the design you created in psd - https://jsfiddle.net/eyc0e5s2/

Answer (score 1):

Based on your included photo, exactly matching the styling of this design will not have a simple answer. To make a simple `<div>` with horizontally scrollable content, you could do something like this:

```css
#wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:none;
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:black;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  }

.photo-box {
  flex:0 0 auto;
  margin:25px;
  background-color:white;
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  }
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div class='photo-box'></div>
  <div class='photo-box'></div>
  <div class='photo-box'></div>
  <div class='photo-box'></div>
  <div class='photo-box'></div>
  <div class='photo-box'></div>
  <div class='photo-box'></div>
</div>
```

However styling things like the scrollbar are not as simple and would require a fair amount more mark-up.

Use a div with `overflow:scroll` as a starting place to get a scrolling box and you can find a jQuery plug-in for making custom scrollbars [here](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/).

Answer (score 0):

Just insert your own images and style the scrollbar.

```css
#scrollable {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 100px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollable">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150%C3%97150&w=150&h=150" />
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150%C3%97150&w=150&h=150" />
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150%C3%97150&w=150&h=150" />
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150%C3%97150&w=150&h=150" />
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150%C3%97150&w=150&h=150" />
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150%C3%97150&w=150&h=150" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. When I put my own images in they appear really spaced out and I tried padding in order to bring them closer together, but this didn't work. Any help? http://prntscr.com/e74zyc

Comment: Use margin-left & right, by about 5px each i would say on each img.